# Preferred way to send large files & metadata to a REST API

Tags: apex

I'm designing a REST API that needs to be able to receive large sensitive files (up to 50MB) along with associated metadata in JSON. Initially, I wanted to use a standard solution based on `multipart/form-data` requests, but Apex's `HttpRequest` class doesn't support it and limits the request size to just 6 MB.

Is there a commonly-used solution that addresses this problem in a Salesforce-friendly manner? e.g. using Google Cloud Storage as an intermediary.

Comment: Please clarify - is Apex initiating a REST callout to a 3rd party system and getting back 50MB file? Or is a 3rd party system calling an SFDC endpoint and supplying to SFDC a 50MB file?

Comment: Apex is sending a 50MB file to a 3rd party REST API.

Comment: if you have control over the third party system, then SFDC sends ContentDocumentId to 3rd party system and 3rd party system then queries using OOTB REST API to fetch ContentVersion data. There's no way (Heap) that Apex can read 50 MB to construct a callout. Renato has the right approach

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a commonly-used solution that addresses this problem in a Salesforce-friendly manner?

It depends on what you define as "friendly". If *friendly* here means *an easy to use, declarative way of setting this up*, then as far as I know, *no*. If *friendly* means *a way to set this up with Salesforce that is API-friendly to the platform, and is easy to integrate (from a developer perspective), update, disable and/or remove*, then yes:

As far as I know there's no free/open source to this as the requirements can change a lot for whoever is asking for a solution like this. But the gist of it is this: handling big files within Salesforce is usually dealt with with a service in between, a **middleware**. This middleware is usually an application or API that you own and is hosted on a public cloud and is responsible for downloading or uploading the data from/to Salesforce.

In your scenario, you would probably need a service that receives coordinates from Salesforce to fetch the file and associated metadata. So Salesforce would POST a request saying which file(s) need to be sent, and what the metadata is, in a JSON payload. The middleware would receive this request, store the JSON data while it downloads the file from Salesforce, and then bundle it all to send to the external system when the download is complete.

[image]

Note that this applies for both sending files to an external system and to sending files to Salesforce. For both the limitation is pretty much the same: the execution time and memory heap in a transaction. The way out is to use API for both sending and receiving big files then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm assuming that the middleware service can use Salesforce's REST API to download files. What would be a good way to identify a file in Salesforce in this case: `contentDocumentId`, `ContentVersion.VersionDataURL`, or something else?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know, to be honest. It varies on the use case. You want files to be uploaded immediately? Might need a trigger. You want specific files to be uploaded? Need to apply some way to differentiate them from others, and maybe let the user choose. I suggest you get acquainted with the content files schema before taking this decision too: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_content.htm